# How to display overflow menu for ToolItems in a GTK Toolbar

Tags: haskell, gtk, gtk3, gtk2

A GTK `Toolbar` can display an overflow menu when the toolbar is not wide enough to show its contents.

It seems that this feature doesn't work if the toolbar contains `ComboBox`es wrapped by `ToolItem`s.

Here is [an example code](https://github.com/maoe/gtk2hs-toolbar-experiment/blob/master/Gtk2Hs.hs) that demonstrates the issue. It's written in Haskell but I guess it shouldn't be too difficult to translate it into other languages.

The instructions to build the repo is written in the [README.md](https://github.com/maoe/gtk2hs-toolbar-experiment#readme).

The last command opens a small GTK window. If you make it bigger you'll see two `ComboBox`es in the window. The problem is that if you make the window narrower a bit, the right `ComboBox` disappears and no overflow menu appears even though `toolbarShowArrow` is enabled.

(Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation on SO to post two screenshots here so I uploaded them on the repo.)

Interestingly if I change the contents of the `Toolbar` from `ToolItem`s to `ToolButton`s for example, I get the overflow menu.

Also I tested this with 3 packages: `gtk` for GTK2, `gtk3` for GTK3, and `gi-gtk` for GTK3 with gobject introspection. All of them have the same issue.

So the question is: is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states this [about `gtk_toolbar_set_show_arrow()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkToolbar.html#gtk-toolbar-set-show-arrow):

> Sets whether to show an overflow menu when `toolbar` doesn’t have room for all items on it. If `TRUE`, items that there are not room are available through an overflow menu.

So, it's an "overflow menu". I won't bore you with a detour into the GTK+ source, but suffice it to say: the items you add to the `Toolbar` need to provide menu items to appear in its overflow menu. Sounds logical now, right? :D

`ToolButtons` work because they call `set_proxy_menu_item()` with a `MenuItem` they create specifically for this purpose.

And that's what `Toolbar` looks for when deciding whether items can overflow: proxy `MenuItem`s, which it can put into the overflow menu - and only if it finds at least one is there any point in giving the arrow to open that menu.

So, if you have other widgets, you can to get them into the overflow menu by setting a proxy menu item on your `ToolItem`, by either of:

- simply calling [`gtk_tool_item_set_proxy_menu_item()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkToolItem.html#gtk-tool-item-set-proxy-menu-item) to set a specific item
- connecting to the `::create-menu-proxy` signal on your `ToolItem`, and deciding during each emission whether or not to set (or clear) the proxy item

You'd also, of course, connect `::activate` on that `MenuItem` to do something appropriate relating to the original `ToolItem`.

...though whether you can do anything useful from a `MenuItem` if the ultimate `ToolItem` child is a `ComboBox` is a different question. It doesn't expose its popup menu as something you can use. I guess you could just add a duplicate of the `ComboBox` to a `MenuItem` and use that as your proxy... But in that case, likely you're outwith the scope of what the overflow menu is meant for, and should instead just ensure your `Toolbar` doesn't get small enough to lose such controls.

Or maybe not! Try it and see how it goes.